# CSS: Float, but don't have anything under

Tags: css

I have around 3 floating `div`s, 2 left and 1 right, then I have some other text content under the 3 floating `div`s. The text gets under the 3 floating elements, how do I do so it doesn't get under it, but should still float?

Comment: Text shouldn't get underneath a floated element, just a `position: absolute` one. Please show some code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some code would help, but with floats usually the problem is that they are not being cleared.

```
<div style="float: left;"></div>
<div style="float: left;"></div>
<div style="float: right;"></div>
<div style="clear: both;">
    <p>some text under the float</p>
</div>
```